# It is possible to have multiple unique constraints in an Azure search index?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Below is the data I'm putting into Azure search:

[image]

`Id` is the unique key on the index.

I'd like to put an additional unique constraint on `EntityName` + `Key`.

I wondered whether this possible in Azure search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the SQL database is the source of truth and you can only put unique constraints on your SQL, not on Azure Cognitive Search.

You can check the details about adding unique constraints to SQL Server databases [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15).

Also, please, excuse me for the offtopic, but the `EntityName` seems more like an `EntityType`, as it is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on wheter you are [pushing data to the index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-data-import#pushing-data-to-an-index) or if you are using a built-in indexer (the so-called pull-model). If you are using the push-model, you decide the constraints with your own code. You are free to combine the Id + Key and use that as your unique identifier.

When you are using the pull-model you don't have this option.